# Could not find a configuration file for package *

Tags: ros, catkin, find-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's a minimal catkin package.

Package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>sighdangitcatkin</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The sighdangitcatkin package</description>
  <maintainer email="dlu@todo.todo">dlu</maintainer>
  <license>TODO</license>
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>orocos_kdl</build_depend>
</package>
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sighdangitcatkin)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS orocos_kdl )
catkin_package()
```

Seems pretty simple, yah? Here's the error I get when compiling.

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sighdangitcatkin'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sighdangitcatkin)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package orocos_kdl.

  Set orocos_kdl_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for orocos_kdl.  The file will have one of the following names:

    orocos_kdlConfig.cmake
    orocos_kdl-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sighdangitcatkin/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

What am I missing?

Note: It works fine if you use this CMake..

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
 project(sighdangitcatkin)
 find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS )
 find_package(orocos_kdl REQUIRED)
 catkin_package()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107346/could-not-find-a-configuration-file-for-package-*/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-12-05

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-05**:
Excuse me , Did this error happen after typing
1-   cd ~/catkin_ws
2-   then typing  catkin_make

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-05**:
Essentially.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-05**:
please, would you make sure that ROS can see & find your package
I mean by that Did you try typing command rospack find ( your_package_name)
or using command roscd (your_package_name) then typing unix command pwd
either using command rospack find or using commands  roscd then pwd
it should return your package path if ROS can find your package in the src folder of catkin_ws in your home
please , make sure of that

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-05**:
Thanks, but William found the real problem.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-05**:
Thanks God .  I am happy that your problem has been solved
I just tried to help .Thanks to Mr William . God bless him amen

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-05**:
@Real Loyalty For future edits of your posts / comments please consider checking the check box "minor edit - don't send alerts" if you modifications are minor (e.g. spelling and white space fixing) to avoid numerous notification emails to subscribed users. Thx.

**Comment by [Eman](https://answers.ros.org/users/6115/eman/) on 2013-12-05**:
@Dirk Thomas  Thx for your note .  I will take care about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like `orocos_kdl` is not a catkin package:

https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/blob/master/orocos_kdl/package.xml#L20

So having catkin find it will not work...

I would recommend you use the `find_package(orocos_kdl REQUIRED)` line in your catkin package.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-05**:
So it is still a package, and a package you can build catkin on top of, but not a catkin package?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-12-05**:
It is a non-catkin package as described in REP-136, just like opencv, console_bridge, and others. We support building it as part of a catkin workspace using catkin_make_isolated as a convenience, but no they are not catkin packages.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-12-06**:
Understood. Is there any way to shortcut the above error message so that it instead says "Attempting to make catkin depend on non-catkin package. Don't do that." or something more helpful than the CMake gobbeldygook?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-12-06**:
I don't believe so, the problem is that orocos_kdl doesn't provide a file called `orocos_kdlConfig.cmake` or `orocos_kdl-config.cmake`, which is what CMake is complaining about. So we don't know if it is a missing package or a package which is not a catkin package. If `orocos_kdl` provided one of those files (as a coincident), then catkin would inform you that it found `orocos_kdl`, but that it is not a catkin package. Additionally, error handling like try-catch is really problematic in CMake, so we would have to completely rewrite parts of CMake's `find_package` to do better error handling.